# Использование камеры и микрофона в браузере

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>getUserMedia Demo 1</title>
  <style>
    video {
      border: 5px solid black;
      width: 480px;
      height: 360px;
    }
    button {
      font: 18px sans-serif;
      padding: 8px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="vid" autoplay="true"></video>
  <br>
  <button id="btn" onclick="start()">Start</button>
  <script>
    video = document.getElementById("vid");

    function start() {
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
        video: true
      }, gotStream, function() {});
      btn.disabled = true;
    }

    function gotStream(stream) {
      video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Код правильный, из книги WebRTC Integrator's Guide. Ни один браузер не спрашивает доступа к камере и не показывает видео. Почему?

Comment: Это нестандартизированные возможности, а значит могут в любой момент поменяться или исчезнуть. В частности в хроме будет работать [только в безопасном режиме](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins), в мозиле он mozGetUserMedia и уже устарел, вместо него [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia). Ну и прочие причины, по которым плохо работают методы, которые не входят в стандарт.

Comment: Спасибо, ребята, вы мне очень помогли)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть отличная статья на хабре: https://habrahabr.ru/post/198632/

Где описываются:

1. `getUserMedia` — получение доступа к медиа устройствам (микрофон/вебкамера)
2. `Signaling server` (сигнальный сервер)
3. `WebRTC` проблемы и использование

Добавлю из комментария **@AlexKrass**:

> В частности в хроме будет работать только в безопасном режиме, в мозиле он `mozGetUserMedia` и уже устарел, вместо него `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`.