# WebRTC. PeerConnection

Tags: webrtc

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>PeerConnection Demo 1</title>
  <!-- Load the polyfill to switch-hit between Chrome and Firefox -->
  <script src="base/adapter.js"></script>
  <style>
    video {
      border: 5px solid black;
      width: 480px;
      height: 360px;
    }
    button {
      font: 18px sans-serif;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    textarea {
      font-family: monospace;
      margin: 2px;
      width: 480px;
      height: 640px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="vid1" autoplay="true" muted="true"></video>
  <video id="vid2" autoplay></video>
  <br>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="start()">Start</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="call()">Call</button>
  <button id="btn3" onclick="hangup()">Hang Up</button>
  <br>
  <xtextarea id="ta1">
    </textarea>
    <xtextarea id="ta2">
      </textarea>
      <script>
        //var vid1 = document.getElementById("vid1");
         //var vid2 = document.getElementById("vid2");
        btn1.disabled = false;
        btn2.disabled = true;
        btn3.disabled = true;
        var pc1, pc2;
        var localstream;
        var sdpConstraints = {
          'mandatory': {
            'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
            'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
          }
        };

        function gotStream(stream) {
          trace("Received local stream");
          // Call the polyfill wrapper to attach the media stream to this element.
          attachMediaStream(vid1, stream);
          localstream = stream;
          btn2.disabled = false;
        }

        function start() {
          trace("Requesting local stream");
          btn1.disabled = true;
          // Call into getUserMedia via the polyfill (adapter.js).
          getUserMedia({
              audio: true,
              video: true
            },
            gotStream, function() {});
        }

        function call() {
          btn2.disabled = true;
          btn3.disabled = false;
          trace("Starting call");
          videoTracks = localstream.getVideoTracks();
          audioTracks = localstream.getAudioTracks();
          if (videoTracks.length > 0)
            trace('Using Video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
          if (audioTracks.length > 0)
            trace('Using Audio device: ' + audioTracks[0].label);
          var servers = null;
          pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
          trace("Created local peer connection object pc1");
          pc1.onicecandidate = iceCallback1;
          pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
          trace("Created remote peer connection object pc2");
          pc2.onicecandidate = iceCallback2;
          pc2.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;

          pc1.addStream(localstream);
          trace("Adding Local Stream to peer connection");

          pc1.createOffer(gotDescription1);
        }

        function gotDescription1(desc) {
          pc1.setLocalDescription(desc);
          trace("Offer from pc1 \n" + desc.sdp);
          pc2.setRemoteDescription(desc);
          // Since the "remote" side has no media stream we need
          // to pass in the right constraints in order for it to
          // accept the incoming offer of audio and video.
          pc2.createAnswer(gotDescription2, null, sdpConstraints);
        }

        function gotDescription2(desc) {
          pc2.setLocalDescription(desc);
          trace("Answer from pc2 \n" + desc.sdp);
          pc1.setRemoteDescription(desc);
        }

        function hangup() {
          trace("Ending call");
          pc1.close();
          pc2.close();
          pc1 = null;
          pc2 = null;
          btn3.disabled = true;
          btn2.disabled = false;
        }

        function gotRemoteStream(e) {
          vid2.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
          trace("Received remote stream");
        }

        function iceCallback1(event) {
          if (event.candidate) {
            pc2.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
            trace("Local ICE candidate: \n" + event.candidate.candidate);
          }
        }

        function iceCallback2(event) {
          if (event.candidate) {
            pc1.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
            trace("Remote ICE candidate: \n " + event.candidate.candidate);
          }
        }
      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Не работает ни в одном браузере. Код из книги WebRTC Integrator's Guide. Я скачал библиотеку adapter.js по [ссылке](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter).
При клике на Start браузер должен запросить камеру и микрофон и показать в первом окне и должна активировать кнопка Call. При нажатии Call видео должно отправиться во второе окно и активироваться кнопка Hang Up. Не работает ничего, браузер даже не запрашивает камеру с микрофоном и не показывает изображение. В чем проблема?

Comment: `ReferenceError: trace is not defined`. Браузерная консоль бывает полезна.

Comment: что это значит? я только начинаю учить эту технологию.

Comment: Это означает, что вы не знаете не только WebRTC, но и JavaScript. Будьте последовательны, начните с JS.

Comment: Начните с изучения javascript. Когда его изучите - тогда уже переходите к технологиям, которые построены на нем.

Comment: А книжку сожгите. Нельзя писать учебные примеры *так*.

Comment: это единственная книга которую я нашел в интернете бесплатно.

Comment: @Айдар http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520521/ недавно задавали такой вопрос. И на самом деле, вам правильно пишут, что без знаний js лучше не лезть туда, что написано на нем, т.к. вы ничего не поймете

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, это я задавал. с этим я уже разобрался. а этот пример совсем другой.

Comment: если я хочу использовать WebRTC в андроид приложении, все равно нужно учить JavaScript?

Comment: @Айдар точно, не посмотрел на создателя того вопроса. Раз уж у вас есть код ошибки, можно по стактрейсу пройти и посмотреть где падает. Видимо это какая-то переменная `trace` не пришла куда ей было положено придти. Про использование WebRTC да, это же функциональность (хоть и новая) `JS'a`

Comment: видимо, придется и JavaScript изучать. Ничего не понял из того, что вы написали.

Comment: @Айдар :)) ну у вас вылетела ошибка в консоли: `trace is not defined` это означает, что переменная используемая в коде не существует (у неё нет значения), но она пытается использоваться, в консоли можно пройти к месту падения этой ошибки и посмотреть в чем косяк, и откуда должна эта переменная браться

Comment: Это наверное из-за неправильно установленного adapter.js, либо я вообще скачал не тот adapter.js. я так понял, что он нужен для того, чтобы не писать префиксы для каждого браузера. не подскажете, какой адаптер мне нужно скачивать?